# Is there a method to impersonate another bot to send an embed in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a game bot, however I have encountered a tricky situation. I want to be able to make my bot look like a different bot entirely, by temporarily changing the name and avatar to send an embed. I have tried:

```
with open("shadytrader.png", "rb") as img:
    await client.user.edit(
        username="The shady trader",
        avatar=img.read()
    )
```

Which works fine until I want to change the name back, at which point discord either bugs out and shows none of the changes, or raises an error telling me that I am changing the bots name and avatar too fast. I also tried  `embed.set_author("Shady trader", "icon_url"`, which just makes the embed look worse and does not change the image or name of the bot when sending the message.

Is there a way to temporarily and reliably change the name and icon of the bot to send an embed?

Comment: have you tried changing the `nickname` instead of the actual name of the bot?

Comment: You should be using webhooks instead for this. Webhooks allow you to send a message with any name/avatar you want and they stay that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord only lets you change your name twice every hour and the changes may take up to an hour to be shown to everyone, you don't have any influence on that. Also, when you change the name, the messages you sent before the change will update to the new name.

While this method might be the most legitimate looking to random people seeing it, another method you could try (what i personally would recommend you) is to send the message using a webhook. I put together this solution that temporarily creates a webhook that looks like another user when used. Simply replace `ORIGINAL_USER_ID` with the [User ID](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) of the account you are trying to imitate.

```
# The original user is fetched from its ID
# Change 'ORIGINAL_USER_ID' to the ID of the user you are trying to imitate
original = await client.fetch_user('ORIGINAL_USER_ID')

# Downloading the avatar of the user you are trying to imitate
import requests
req = requests.get(url=original.avatar.url)
avatar = req.content

# Creating the webhook looking like the user
webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=original.name, avatar=avatar)

# Sending the message. Set this to anything you want.
await webhook.send("This message looks like it was sent by someone else.")

# Here you can do whatever you want with the webhook...

# Deleting the webhook when everything is done
await webhook.delete()
```

This code also automatically downloads the avatar and the username, if you want to use your own method feel to put in your code, this is not related to the webhooks.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The webhook idea is good, but do you have an alternative to changing the ID? Sorry for not clarifying, but there is not actual user I want to impersonate, instead, I want to change my bot to look like a completely different bot (and a bot that does not exist). I will look at using webooks though!

Comment: @Helppls  You can pass anything you want to the name and avatar attributes. It doesn't have to come from another user

Comment: @Helppls like i said at the end, you can use any code you want to. `name` needs a `str` object and `avatar` needs a `bytes` object (just like the one you create with loading the imagine in your original question.

Comment: Don't use `requests`, discord.py. has a built in **async** method for downloading the avatar file.